# str_replace just returns caps

Tags: php, str-replace

i have a lil problem here..i'm using `str_replace` to replace the most common words..and for some reason its replacing every letter except caps.

for example..if i had the code below

```
$str ="Fat string of Text.";    
$commonwords = array('fat','of','random');
$cleantext = str_replace($commonwords,'',$str);
```

`echo $cleantext;`

it would echo.. `F T`

any ideas what i did wrong..
thanks in advance

and oh..i tried `str_ireplace`.. but nothing

Comment: Works for me. `str_replace()` gives me `Fat string  Text.` and `str_ireplace()` gives me ` string  Text.`. Are you sure you're showing us the actual code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This echos **"Fat string Text"**.

**Your PHP installation may be wrong** or your posted code that does **not exactly match** the program you are running

Also, [`str_ireplace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) echos **"string Text"**.

Comment: found the proble'm..

some of the words in my array were like-> i've,can't <-- the apostrophes were making the problem..thanks for the help

Comment: Yup, escape your apostrophes :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce that on PHP 5.3.3.  I get:

```
php > $str ="Fat string of Text.";
php > $commonwords = array('fat','of','random');
php > $cleantext = str_replace($commonwords,'',$str);
php > echo $cleantext;
Fat string  Text.
php > $cleantext = str_ireplace($commonwords,'',$str);
php > echo $cleantext;
 string  Text.
```

as expected.